# Jquery datepicker behave weird in IE browser

Tags: internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-datepicker

i have set StartDate and EndDate at runtime using View model value. using "setDate".

and same for the End date. Here Date values are coming from model and i am setting these values in java script.

Now, MY PROBLEM IS these date displays correctly if IE browser language is "en-US" but   it is not working if language is "en-IN". I am using windows 7 OS and IE 10.
Can u please help me out ..?

Initialization :

```
          // Initialize DatePicker
        $(function () {
            $("#datepickerStartDate").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "../../Images/date.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            dateFormat: "d MM yy",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear:true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            startDate = selectedDate;
            $("#datepickerEndDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);

           }
        });
     });
```

Startdate and End date value is coming from View model and follow xode i have used for that.

```
$("#datepickerStartDate").datepicker("setDate", (new Date("@Model.EstimatedStartDate.ToString()")));
    // Set min date of EndDatePicker.
    $("#datepickerEndDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", (new Date("@Model.EstimatedStartDate.ToString()")));
```

Also i have tried to set date picker regional to "en-US" but still it is not working.